# Show dapp favicon in trustwallet

Tags: html, favicon, decentralized-applications, trustwallet

I have a very small and silly problem. I have developed a dapp. But trustwallet does not show the favicon of the dapp, in its history or in the url as it shows for other dapps like Pancakeswap. While Metamask shows the favicon.

This is the html to show the icon:

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/favicon.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

Is there anything else I need to do to show that favicon in TrustWallet?
I need to do this, my client is stubborn.

Comment: My team has this exact issue.  I'm surprised that no knowledgable person has answered this question in 2 months.

Comment: Looking for the answer as well

Comment: Didn't find the answer yet!